# SSIS Change Data Capture on Table with Child Relations

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and am having a hard time finding information on this.  My source is a SQLDB and my Target is a SQLDB

In my source I have a Table with a FK reference to a different table.  I want to Extract the Parent with Child from Source and Load them into a single flat table in my Target.

```
Select * From Table1 Left Join Table2 on Table1.Table2Id = Table2.Id
```

Within my Dataflow i have an OLE DB Source where i am using the DataAccessMode of SQL Command and using the Query Above.

However, I am looking to do Change Data Capture so i can track Incremental changes and not do wipe and loads.  From My Understanding the Change Data Capture Checks is for Table changes.  So if i was to set it up on Table 1, it would only track the changes for Table1. How would I be able to import Table1 and Table2 into the flat table in my Target with Change Data Capture?

Comment: I haven't actually used CDC so I can't speak to how robust this guide is. But for once Microsoft seems to have a half-decent tutorial on SSIS CDC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16